# Seeking an RNA Sequence Tokenizer akin to OpenAI's tiktoken for Text

Tags: bioinformatics

I want to train a language model tailored specifically for RNA sequences. Given the success of language models in the NLP domain, I believe there's significant potential to extract intricate patterns, motifs, and structures from RNA sequences using similar techniques. However, a major challenge I foresee is the tokenization of RNA sequences.

While the immediate idea might be to tokenize based on the four nucleotides (A, C, G, U), I'm convinced that a simple mapping like ($A \rightarrow 0$), ($C \rightarrow 1$), and so forth, won't capture the complexities and nuances of RNA sequences, especially when feeding into a language model.

To give an idea of the data, here's an example row from RNACEN:

`(8988364, 'URS00008926CC', datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 20, 18, 4, 7), 'RNACEN', 'AE0439B061E1640E', 1409, 'GTCGAACGGTAACAGGAAGCAGCTTGCTGCTTTGCTGACGAGTGGCGGACGGGTGAGTAATGTCTGGGAAACTGCCTGATGGAGGGGGATAACTACTGGAAACGGTGGCTAATACCGCATAACGTCGCAAGACCAAAGAGGGGGACCTT ... (1111 characters truncated) ... TCGACTCCATGAAGTCGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGTGGATCAGAATGCCACGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCATGGGAGTGGGTTGCAAAAGAAGTAGGTAGCTTAACCTTCGGGAGGGCGCTTACCAC', None, '5ebae3845f9c331ae71786ed8c0fa100')`

#### Key Concerns:

- **Depth of Tokenization:** How can we tokenize RNA sequences in a manner that captures more than just individual nucleotides? Are there techniques that can encapsulate motifs, secondary structures, or other biological features inherent to RNA?
- **Compatibility with Language Models:** The tokenizer should be designed such that it's effective when used as input for deep learning models, especially language models like transformers.
- **Efficiency and Scalability:** Given the vast amounts of RNA sequence data available, the tokenization method should be efficient and scalable to handle large datasets.

#### Questions:

1. What advanced tokenization techniques are recommended for RNA sequences, especially when the end goal is to train a language model?
2. Are there existing tools or libraries that offer sophisticated RNA tokenization, beyond the basic 0,1,2,3 mapping for the four nucleotides?

***EDIT:***

Currently, I have collected all RNA sequences from RAN Central and created a vocabulary using byte pair encoding (BPE) with 1000 tokens.

Comment: Interesting question. I'm sure there should be many academic papers on this. AphaGo and AlphaFold are examples where systems learned high level abstractions from very low level combinatorial inputs. So maybe analysing that work could give some ideas.